# Xcode storyboard interface bind items to Popup Button

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift2

Building Osx application using swift.I am trying to add "Pop Up Button" object to storyboard window and and populate those items list with my own array.

How to Programmatically Populate add items to "Popup button" list in Swift?